# Importing file into maple on a mac, correct filepath or default directory

Tags: path, maple

I want to import a (text) file into maple on a mac.

According to all available information, the command should be of the form

> read "MacIntosh HD/Programme/myfile"

but I did not succeed.

I tried various variations, slash/backslash, slash at the beginning, with and without Mac HD at the beginning, local language and English language name for the system directories.

I always get

> Error, unable to read `pathname I entered`.

I would be content with any solution, either the syntax, or the default maple directory where I can put the file without worrying about the path or the existence of a menu item with the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself in the meantime:

For the above example
read "/Applications/myfile";

would succeed, so in particular, one has to use the English names for the systems directories even though in finder they are only ever given in the language you chose for your account.

Also, currentdir() and currentdir("Applications/Maple 15") allows you to see the current directory and to change it, respectively.